# R markdown: Remove container div when compiling to html

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, r-markdown

So I want to compile Rmarkdown files and include the compiled html in blog posts on my blog. Specifically, I am using jquery to load in the compiled html document in an existing blog posts.

R markdown by default however puts all the page content in a container div with the classes container-fluid and main-container. As my original blog post already finds itself within a container div, the result is double spacing for the compiled R markdown part of the post.

Is there any way by which I can automatically remove the container div in the compiled R markdown file? Are there options which I could include in the header of the Rmarkdown file that enable this behavior?

Comment: If you are using jQuery to load the file, why not use jQuery to modify it?

Answer (score 2):

See the rmarkdown docs http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html

> If want to create an HTML fragment rather than a full HTML document you can use the html_fragment format. For example:

```
---
output: html_fragment
---
```

> Note that there is no title or author because fragments don’t contain the standard header content that HTML documents do. HTML fragments are typically used for including snippets of HTML within larger web sites (e.g. blogs).